# Select multiple object in one query on a different where clause for each object

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I currently have two querys, which share the same complex query, which I only want to execute once:

```
//Query 1
from together in (...) // ... = Complex query with multiple joins
where together.property == 0
select new { ... }

//Query 2
from together in (...) // ... = Complex query with multiple joins
where together.property > 0
select new { ... }
```

The problem is, that they have a different where clause. I tried to set the where clause in the select statement, but this only seems to be possible, if I use `groupby` which I don't need here:

```
//Don't work
from together in (...) // ... = Complex query with multiple joins
select new {
    //if together would be grouped, this would work. However I need all data without grouping
    //            . Together is not IQueryable so this does not work
    Foo = together.Where(e => e.property == 0).Select(...),
    Bar = together.Where(e => e.property > 0).Select(...)
}
```

Is it possible to get 2 objects based on a different where clause in one query with LINQ?

Comment: Is it throwing a `DoesNotWorkException`?

Comment: `together` is not `IQueryable` in `select new` @SamIam

Comment: Are the Query1/2 selects also the same?

Comment: The selects are different, but the needed data for it the same @IvanStoev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could query them all, and then split them up, like this

```
var qry= (
    from together in (...) // ... = Complex query with multiple joins
    where together.property => 0
    select together)
    .ToList();

var result = new {
    Foo = qry.Where(e => e.property == 0).Select(...),
    Bar = qry.Where(e => e.property > 0).Select(...)
};
```

Comment: This would be a solution, thank you. But I am dealing with a large set of data. Do you think this would be possible with translated SQL only?

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt what are you going to do with the result of that query after you build it?  If you're just going to query the whole thing at once anyway, this approach should not introduce any new performance concerns

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt if `.Select(...)` only selects a small subset, that could affect performance.  Is it possible to select before you check property?

Comment: Many things of the selects are `Sum` in condition of the property. And in my real scenario it's about 6 of them. However I will give it a go, and do some benchmarks.